# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::appends()

Tags: pagination, group-by, laravel-5

My problem is  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::appends()

My query is:

```
$companies=\App\Payment::where('company_id',$id)->paginate(10)->groupBy('month')->groupBy('job_id');
```

Error on pagination

```
{!! $companies->appends(['sort' => 'created_at'])->render() !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are getting a collection object instead of paginator object.

When you called `groupBy` and assign it to the `$companies` variable you have a collection object, which does not have a `appends` method.

Instead assign the paginator to the companies variable and group it later.

```
$companies=\App\Payment::where('company_id',$id)->paginate(10);
```